# Use custom loader in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

how to use custom loader instead of the default in Nextjs

```
const isRefreshing= true;

if (isRefreshing){ return <CustomLoading />}
```

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: Next js show some loader when page is refreshing but I don't want that.

Comment: In development ? Can you share a screenshot ?

Comment: Yes in development. I don't know when to implement this logic so can you let me know which part of the code to take screen shot of or my nextjs.config file?

Comment: Are you talking about [this loader](https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20211021164450/fastrefresh.gif)?

Comment: Yes exactly, that one!

Comment: What is the purpose of changing it since it is hidden in production ?

Comment: Oh did not know. I'm new to it and building my first web app. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it’s a development only feature (hidden in production) there is not a real interest of hiding it.